# How to count repeat list in list? python

Tags: python, count

How to count repeat list in a list?
It is a large List of 99999 elements, and each element is still a list which has two tuples like this: `[(1,2,3,4),(3,4,2,1)]`. I want to count the duplicate list in the list.

[image]

---

I have done something similar: count repeat tuple in a list.
[image]

But it doesn't work when count repeat list in a list.

```
from collections import Counter
Gn=MHs1(phi)
n=dict(Counter(Gn))
print(n)
```

result：

```
{(1, 3, 2, 4): 163038, (1, 2, 3, 4): 330864, (3, 4, 1, 2): 17469, (2, 3, 1, 4): 162774, (1, 4, 2, 3): 163430, (2, 4, 1, 3): 162424}
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50599640/edit) with a [mcve]? In this case, desired output for a given input will help us understand precisely what you require.

Comment: Convert your list of lists to a list of tuples using `[tuple(x) for x in lst]` and do the same as before. Whether lists or tuples, their count is not affected. `list`s are *unhashable* and can therefore **not** be used by `Counter`

Comment: Thanks, Ev. Kounis. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with lists is that they are unhashable, and therefore can't be counted by `Counter`. What about converting your lists to tuples (which are hashable) on the fly and using the same approach?

```
from collections import Counter

Gn = [[(tuple(np.random.choice(range(2),4)), tuple(np.random.choice(range(2),4)))] for i in range(1000)]
n = dict(Counter([tuple(i) for i in Gn]))
print(n)
```

**Output**

```
{(((0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)),): 3,
 (((0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)),): 4,
 (((0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0)),): 4,
 (((0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1)),): 3,
...}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am a beginner and just know how to convert lists to tuples